# Silent printer application using javax and pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf, printing

I'm writing a silent printer application. I have some problem to complete my application.

```
    printRequestAttributeSet.add(printerTray);
    printRequestAttributeSet.add(Sides.ONE_SIDED);

    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader();
    PDDocument document = pdfReader.loadPdf(pdfPath);

    job.setPageable(document);
    int firstno = 0;
    int LastNo = 0;
    String pageRange[] = style.split("-");
    firstno = Integer.parseInt(pageRange[0]);
    if (pageRange[1].equals("Last")) {
        LastNo = document.getNumberOfPages();
    } else {
        LastNo = Integer.parseInt(pageRange[1]);
    }

    printRequestAttributeSet.add(new PageRanges(firstno, LastNo));

    job.printDialog(printRequestAttributeSet);

    job.print();
    // PrintJobWatcher pjDone = new PrintJobWatcher (job);

    document.close();
```

This code is working fine with out any problem. But I want to remove the `job.printDialog(printRequestAttributeSet);` from my code because it always needs user input. Some guys give me some examples at http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI. but I don't know how to set the `printRequestAttributeSet`.

Comment: Guys!! I'm looking some one help to fix my program.

Comment: Commenting on your own questions probably doesn't bump them.

Answer (score 0):

From the Java standard documentation of [PrinterJob](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/print/PrinterJob.html) you can find `PrinterJob#print(PrintRequestAttributeSet)` that does the trick. So call

> job.print(printRequestAttributeSet);

Comment: Isn't this the exact same code the OP already has? I fail to see how that helps with whatever problem he's having.

Comment: thank you for spotting the error, sample was not coherent with above solution. Edited.